# What will be the key size for rsa, ecdhe and ecdsa from the cipher suite given?

Tags: rsa, diffie-hellman, tls, dsa

From the cipher suites `tls_rsa_with_aes_128_cbc_sha256`  and `tls_ecdhe_ecdsa_with_aes_128_cbc_sha256` how do I know what will be the RSA , ECDHE, and ECDSA key support in IBM cloud Watson?

[here is the link to IBM cipher suites support](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.gska100/csdcwh.htm)

Comment: The key size for (symmetric) data encryption is negotiated as part of the ciphersuite, 
 See [https://stackoverflow.com/a/41685647/1820553]

Comment: And the Watson has pages for that too. I've googled just IBM Watson RSA key size. https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.icha700/keysizec.htm

Comment: In other words: the size of the RSA and ECDSA keys depend on the certificates of the parties. I have no idea for the ECDHE parameters, especially when the parties have ECDSA keys with differing parameters/curves.

Comment: i think the Watson pages that you've mentioned is actually for mainframes not for ibm watson cloud...https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.icha700/keysizec.htm